# Estou tentando conectar o mysql no php?

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde

estou tentando conetctar o mysql no php, pois esta gerando o seguinte erro " Call to undefined function mysql_conect()", alguem por favor poderia me ajudar

Comment: mysql_connect() parece que faltou 1 n.

Comment: cara valeu nao tinha visto muito obrigado deu certo

Comment: Só vou colocar como resposta depois você coloca como certa. Clicando no V transparente, aí ele fica verde! Valeu!

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque é sobre um erro de digitação no código-fonte, e dificilmente será útil para futuros visitantes.

Comment: Sobre pedir pro OP dar accept, [já foi discutido no meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1425/). Agora, pedir accept por um "praticamente comentário" acho mais forçado ainda...

Comment: @RogersCorrêa, o destino deste tipo de perguntas é a remoção/delete/evaporação, levando *upvotes* e *accepts* com ela. É melhor focar em perguntas de qualidade. Mendigar *accepts* não é elegante, não... confira o meta post linkado pelo Bacco.

Comment: Mas ele precisava de ajuda :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou um n, em vez de *conect* seria **connect** `mysql_connect(blabla);`, além diso devo avisar que em futuras versões do PHP *(3anos?)* seu código deixará de funcionar, e se você estiver trabalhando para um cliente, isso vai ser ruim, visto que mysql_connect foi *descontinuado* (será removido no futuro), além disso ele é mais mais inseguro.

Sugiro que comece a usar *mysqli* ou *PDO*, links de tutoriais básicos:

> http://blog.thiagobelem.net/guia-pratico-de-mysqli-no-php/ (mysqli)
>
> http://www.rafaelwendel.com/2011/12/tutorial-pdo-php-data-object/ (PDO)

Espero ter ajudado.